# Cache Clearing Not Working

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser, browser-cache

I am at my whits end. I have just managed to set up a DNS change for a wordpress managed site, it was working fine I was in the back-end and then I keep getting this blue webpage with this URL (http://81.21.76.62/index.html?domain=globalone.org.uk) when I try and go back to it. I have called the domain company and the wordpress hosting company and both of them can see the site as it should be, I have tried on another computer and it works fine. I have tried on Chrome, Firefox and IE and have cleared all of the caches on these multiple times, I have restarted the browser AND the computer but it's still not working. Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

DNS can be and usually is cached by local ISP and home routers for zone `Refresh` time, which is usually several hours (for domain in your link it is 4 hours, at the time of writing)

Before that cache expires - you can check the site by manually resolving on authoritative nameserver and injecting the ip:

```
% host globalone.org.uk ns.123-reg.co.uk
Using domain server:
Name: ns.123-reg.co.uk
Address: 212.67.202.2#53
Aliases:

globalone.org.uk has address 160.153.136.1

% curl -v 160.153.136.1 -H 'Host: globalone.org.uk'

*   Trying 160.153.136.1...
* Connected to 160.153.136.1 (160.153.136.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: globalone.org.uk
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< X-Pingback: http://www.globalone.org.uk/xmlrpc.php
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Port: port_10444
< X-Cacheable: YES:Forced
< Location: http://www.globalone.org.uk/
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 04 Apr 2016 16:59:53 GMT
< Age: 0
< Vary: User-Agent
< X-Cache: uncached
< X-Cache-Hit: MISS
< X-Backend: all_requests
```

(the above shows that your wordpress is working fine, but you have to wait for DNS to update)